# Why do you need to have round brackets around attribute values for XAML animations?

Tags: wpf, xaml

This has been bugging me for a long time now and I can't seem to find a good explanation for it. What is the purpose of the round brackets in this markup? Is it a XAML shortcut for casting? Why does it only seem to be used for animations?

```
Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is syntax for specifying a Type qualified `DependencyProperty`.  It is required, because the `Storyboard.TargetProperty` attached property can be attached to any `DependencyObject`. That means the XAML parser won't know how to resolve the properties unless they are fully qualified.

This syntax is also used for things like binding to attached properties.  Here is a contrived example to demonstrate this:

```
<Grid>  
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border x:Name="Foo" Background="Blue" Grid.Row="10" />
    <Border x:Name="Bar" Background="Red" Height="{Binding (Grid.Row), ElementName=Foo}" />
</Grid>
```

If you remove the parenthesis from the `Binding`, you'll get a binding error (because there is no Grid property on the `Border` element).

Answer (score 0):

It isn't only used for animations (Validation springs to mind) - they are simply static calls or casts, respectively. Basically the above code translates to (in pseudo-code):

```
((RotateTransform)TextBlock.GetRenderTransform((TextBlock) element)).Angle = newValue;
```

where element is the element that is acted upon and newValue is the animation setting properties.